# git reset ---hard returns error

Tags: git, git-reset

I am git newbie.
When I hope to reset hard to discard all local modification, git return merge conflict

> HEAD is now at 3291a25 will create merge conflict 1

my operation:

1. about half a month I commit as below

   ```
   git commit -am "will create merge conflict 1"
   ```
2. today I hope to reset --hard to this ref

   ```
   yaoyangyong@ubuntulucky:~/repos01$ git reset --hard HEAD
   HEAD is now at 3291a25 will create merge confict 1
   ```
3. The output confuse me. In fact, it is just my old comment.

Comment: do you had deleted files or untracked files before reseting?

Comment: That output is correct: git is telling you you have reset to the last commit on HEAD and is showing the commit message as a reminder of where you are now.

Comment: Your question has no question in it. Please edit it to make it clear what your asking or it will get flagged. Right now it makes no sense. Like Josh said the output is all good. And your header makes even less sense because you have not provided any printings/output that would demonstrate any errors. If there is an error you should add that to your posting as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git is simply telling you the result of the reset.

HEAD(your current position) is now at 3291a25(the commit you wanted to reset to) "will create merge confict 1"(the message of the commit).

You should pass a commit which you want to reset to rather than just say `HEAD`. Also, if you want to abort a half completed merge, use `git merge --abort` (or `git reset --merge` in older versions of git).